# Drawing in MigraDoc document using XGraphics

Tags: pdfsharp, migradoc

I have generated some PDF report using MigraDoc. Initial code is as follows:-

```
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document document = new MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document();

MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Section section = document.AddSection();
...

Paragraph paragraph = section.Headers.Primary.AddParagraph();
....

table = section.AddTable();
...

paragraph = section.Footers.Primary.AddParagraph();
...
```

The PDF was rendered successfully. Now I want to add some graphics into the pages of this document. I have gone through several articles for that and found that everyone using **PdfDocument** class instead of **MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document**. Is it possible to apply graphics into pages of a document of type **MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document** using XGraphics? If it is not possible, what is the best way to mix **PdfDocument** with **MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document** to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MigraDoc uses PDFsharp and an XGraphics object to create the PDF pages.

There are several ways to add content to pages created by MigraDoc.

This MigraDoc sample shows some options:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/MixMigraDocAndPdfSharp-sample.ashx

You can even call MigraDoc to use "your" XGraphics object for drawing:

```
// Alternative rendering with progress indicator.
// Set a callback for phase 1.
pdfRenderer.DocumentRenderer.PrepareDocumentProgress += PrepareDocumentProgress;
// Now start phase 1: Preparing pages (i.e. calculate the layout).
pdfRenderer.PrepareRenderPages();

// Now phase 2: create the PDF pages.
Console.WriteLine("\r\nRendering document ...");

int pages = pdfRenderer.DocumentRenderer.FormattedDocument.PageCount;
for (int i = 1; i <= pages; ++i)
{
    var page = pdfRenderer.PdfDocument.AddPage();
    Console.Write("\rRendering page " + i + "/" + pages);

    PageInfo pageInfo = pdfRenderer.DocumentRenderer.FormattedDocument.GetPageInfo(i);
    page.Width = pageInfo.Width;
    page.Height = pageInfo.Height;
    page.Orientation = pageInfo.Orientation;

    using (XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page))
    {
        gfx.MUH = pdfRenderer.Unicode ? PdfFontEncoding.Unicode : PdfFontEncoding.WinAnsi;
        gfx.MFEH = pdfRenderer.FontEmbedding;
        pdfRenderer.DocumentRenderer.RenderPage(gfx, i);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("\r\nSaving document ...");
```

Sample code taken from this post:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=9293#p9293